# Game of Life array edges acting weird

Tags: c++, arrays, conways-game-of-life

I saw Conway's Game of Life and decided to make my own.
I have a bool array to represent the world, but the edges (Top and bottom) are acting weird, random cells becomes live.

In this code, it does not print the bottom and top of the world, but this is a bad solution.
The world "wraps" at the right and the left, causing even more problems, but that is for another time.

```
#include <iostream>

const int height = 20;
const int width  = 20;

bool now_world[height][width];
bool then_world[height][width];

void clear_world();
void place_random_live_cells();
void then_world_initialization();
void print_world();
void generation_pass();
void update_worlds();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
using namespace std;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
int timer = 0;
int generation = 0;
clear_world();
place_random_live_cells();
then_world_initialization();
bool running = true;
while (running) {
    if (timer == 50000000) {
        cout << "Generation #" << generation << endl;
        print_world();
        generation_pass();
        update_worlds();
        ++generation;
        timer = 0;
    }
    ++timer;
}//While (running) ends here
return 0;
}

void place_random_live_cells()
{
int percent = 30;
int max_live_cells = ((height * width) / 100) * percent;
int current_live_cells = 0;
while (current_live_cells < max_live_cells) {
    int ycoords = 0 + (rand() % (height + 1));
    int xcoords = 0 + (rand() % (width  + 1));
    if (now_world[ycoords][xcoords] == false) {
        now_world[ycoords][xcoords] = true;
    } else {
        current_live_cells--;
    }
    ++current_live_cells;
}
}

//A generation pass and cells die and some cells come to life
void generation_pass()
{
using namespace std;
int neighbours = 0;
for (int iii = 0; iii < height; iii++) {
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < width; jjj++) {
        //Count neighbouring cells that are alive
        if (now_world[iii+1][jjj+1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        if (now_world[iii+1][jjj  ] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        if (now_world[iii+1][jjj-1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        if (now_world[iii  ][jjj+1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        if (now_world[iii  ][jjj-1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        if (now_world[iii-1][jjj+1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        if (now_world[iii-1][jjj  ] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        if (now_world[iii-1][jjj-1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
        //Apply rules to the cells
        //Dead cells with three live neighbours becomes alive
        if (then_world[iii][jjj] == false && neighbours == 3) {
            then_world[iii][jjj] =  true;
        }
        //Alive with fewer than two, they die
        if (then_world[iii][jjj] == true  && neighbours <  2) {
            then_world[iii][jjj] =  false;
        }
        //Alive with 2 or three live neighbours live on unchanged
        if (then_world[iii][jjj] == true  && neighbours == 2) {
            then_world[iii][jjj] =  true;
        }
        if (then_world[iii][jjj] == true  && neighbours == 3) {
            then_world[iii][jjj] =  true;
        }
        //Alive with more than three, they die
        if (then_world[iii][jjj] == true  && neighbours >  3) {
            then_world[iii][jjj] =  false;
        }
        //Dead cells without exactly three live neighbours remain dead
        //Reset neighbour value to zero
        neighbours = false;
    }
}
}

//Make next generation identical to current
//This is only called once
void then_world_initialization()
{
for (int iii = 0; iii < height; iii++) {
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < width; jjj++) {
        then_world[iii][jjj] = now_world[iii][jjj];
    }
}
}

//Make the next generation be today
//This is called every generation
void update_worlds()
{
for (int iii = 0; iii < height; iii++) {
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < width; jjj++) {
        now_world[iii][jjj] = then_world[iii][jjj];
    }
}
}

//Set all cells to dead
void clear_world()
{
for (long iii = 0; iii < height; iii++) {
    for (long jjj = 0; jjj < width; jjj++) {
        now_world[iii][jjj]  = false;
        then_world[iii][jjj] = false;
    }
}
}

//Print world
void print_world()
{
using namespace std;
char live = 'X';
char dead = '.';
for (long iii = height; iii > 0; iii--) {
    for (long jjj = width; jjj > 0; jjj--) {
        if (iii != 0 && iii != height) {
            if (now_world[iii][jjj]) {
                cout << live;
            } else {
                cout << dead;
            }
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: this is so obvious... what do you think is so special about the edges?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that they don't exists.
But how do we fix this?

Comment: What is your intended behavior for edges? Wrap around? Never change?

Comment: Top and bottom, the program tries to access world[-1][something] and that won't work.

Comment: I know. What do you want to happen?

Comment: Then check if [-1] would be out of bounds and process if it was a dead cell... or a living cell, when you prefer.

Comment: @zch I want to ignore the out of boundary value and carry on.
A normal cell has eight adjacent pieces, edge must have five and corner three.

Comment: Ok guys, I fixed it.
I simply made the array one longer in every direction then make all those cells dead every turn and then I do not print them.
This fixed everything, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done this for a course I taught in the past, the most common issue I always see people having is going outside the bounds of the array they're using.

If you look at the if statements in your nested for loop, I think you'll find some issues.  For instance, in this case, what happens when iii equals (height-1) or jjj equals (width-1)?

```
for (int iii = 0; iii < height; iii++) {
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < width; jjj++) {
        //Count neighbouring cells that are alive
        if (now_world[iii+1][jjj+1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
```

You're going outside the bounds of your array and so your results will be undefined.  You may get segfaults, but you may just also get spurious data.  C++ doesn't enforce you staying within the bounds of the array you define.

Make sure you also handle cases like this:

```
if (now_world[iii-1][jjj+1] == true) {
            ++neighbours;
        }
```

What if iii equals zero?

Hope that helps.

Comment: I suspected this was the case, and I think that if they try to read values outside of the array, they read them as true? if not, there would not be cells coming live at the edge.
Also I don't see the difference in our if statements except for whitespace.

Comment: @Lemonizer Avoid the use of "== true" , "== false" etc at boolean conditions/expressions. It's redundant. This is not a critic, it's only a style advice :)

Comment: @Lemonizer - I didn't change any of your code, I just copy/pasted it as an example.  If you go outside the bounds of your array, the behavior is just undefined.  It could come back true, it could come back false or it could crash.  That's why making sure you stay within your array bounds is critical; because otherwise the results are unpredictable.

Comment: @BrentNash I see. Thank you. While you were gone I fixed the problem and I made it write the world to a .txt file every generation.
I want it to compare itself to every previous generation to see if it has entered a cycle.
This week will be a fun week for sure!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access out-of-boundary indexes in your array.

I'm not sure what behaviour you expect, but an easy way is to not calculate updates for cells on the edges.

So in `generation_pass` the loops should go from `1` till `height-1`.

Comment: I don't think this will work, these cells will not be able to perish, as they are never handled.

Comment: don't set them, don't show them, etc... it's still a lot easier than checking for every boundary condition.